# Admin form select value from dropdown value save in database magento 1.9

Tags: module

I have created custom extension in Magento 1.9.

The idea is to add dropdown select  `question` field form the input value and upon saving, store it within database.

[image]

```
    public function getFieldOptionField()
    {
        $field = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text();
        $field->setName($this->getFieldName().'[{{index}}]['.$this->getFieldTextString().']')
            ->setId($this->getFieldId().'_{{index}}_'.$this->getFieldTextString())
            ->setStyle('width:300px!important;')
            ->setForm(new Varien_Data_Form())
            ->setAfterElementHtml($this->getIdHiddenField().$this->getDeleteHiddenField());

        return $this->toJSTmplHtml($field);
    }
```

Comment: whats your question here? what problem are you facing here?

Comment: now edit my question so please check `getFieldOptionField()` function add option field.

Comment: same way i create `getQuestionField()` function select dropdown field. @Piyush

Comment: If I understood right, do you want to add select field instead of  text?

Comment: Yes any idea how to create.@Piyush

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90663/how-to-add-custom-field-in-custom-module-form-like-a-tier-price-in-product

Comment: Reference for link http://demo.mageplace.com/index.php/admin .cms -> survey -> Manage Question Edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68059/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-piyush).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dropdown instead of text you have to try something like below code

```
public function getFieldOptionField()
{
    $field = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select();
    $field->setName($this->getFieldName().'[{{index}}]['.$this->getFieldTextString().']')
        ->setId($this->getFieldId().'_{{index}}_'.$this->getFieldTextString())
        ->setStyle('width:300px!important;')
        ->setForm(new Varien_Data_Form())
        ->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('your_module/your_model')->toOptionArray());
        ->setAfterElementHtml($this->getIdHiddenField().$this->getDeleteHiddenField());

    return $this->toJSTmplHtml($field);
}
```

In you model's `toOptionArray` method you can add your options like this

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array('value' => 1, 'label' => Mage::helper('your_module')->__('Option 1')),
        array('value' => 0, 'label' => Mage::helper('your_module')->__('Option 2')),
    );
}
```

Comment: already accept your answer.@Piyush

Comment: Please accept my question and answer both are useful text and select field.@Piyush

Comment: your answer is useful but i have changes your answer and updated my answer below so check now.

Answer (score 2):

1. For dropdown instead of select you have to try something like below code.

   ```
   public function getQuestionField()
   {
       $Collection = Mage::getModel('your_module/your_model')->getCollection();

       $quearray = array(array('value'=>0, 'label'=>'Please Select'));

       $currentqid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('question_id');

       foreach ($Collection as $question){

           if($currentqid != $question['question_id']) {
               $quearray[] = array(
                   'value'=>$question['question_id'],
                   'label'=>$question['question_id']
               );
           }
   }

   $field = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select();
   $field->setName($this->getFieldName().'[{{index}}][next_que_id]')
       ->setId($this->getFieldId().'_{{index}}_next_que_id')
       ->setValues($quearray)
       ->setForm(new Varien_Data_Form())
       ->setAfterElementHtml($this->getIdHiddenField().$this->getDeleteHiddenField());

   return $this->toJSTmplHtml($field);
   }
   ```